# CSS transitions always start at user agent style sheet

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm currently fiddling with a website, and I wanted to animate a button's background color on hover. Unfortunately, the button will always start as white (browser default, Firefox) and transition into its proper color.

```css
#controldiv button {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 16pt;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #0f0;
    transition: background-color 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

In HTML world...

```html
    <div id="controldiv">
        <button id="connect">Connect</button>
    </div>
```

The transition from white to the desired color always happens when the page refreshes, which makes it really annoying. Any advice?

Comment: Where is the CSS that does anything on hover?

Comment: I don't need it for the interaction to occur. I simply refresh the page and CSS transitions into itself, as if the properties changed.

Comment: OK, understood. But I've run your code on Firefox (on Windows 10) and the color came up as black immediately (I made the transition time 20s to be absolutely sure). What system are you using?

Comment: I found the issue, but I still don't know the solution. Loading it using inline styles (<style> in the head) works, but using a <link rel="stylesheet" href="file.css"> doesn't. To answer your question, I'm on Windows 10, Firefox 100.0 (64-bit), but I doubt that matters now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was being caused by the styles being loaded by an external stylesheet, and I found a somewhat working solution. By preloading the stylesheet:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="test.css" as="style">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
```

The transition disappears. Unfortunately, the transition still appears on pages loaded from files, but in practice this works (it's a WEBsite after all). If there's a better solution (besides inline styles) out there though, I would love to hear it.